# How to display new line \n in mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
 My actual problem is with the display.@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(@Model.DataText).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")) ...
```

here in my textarea text new line is \n ..and Environment.NewLine is actually \r\n. so it is not replacing with a break satement.What should i use instead of Environment.NewLine.

Comment: How are you sending it to SQL Server?

Comment: i have identified that if i use text view in sql i can see new line , if i use grid view it will not show the new line. My statement is wrong and is actually saving the data. My actual problem is with the display.@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(@Model.DataText).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"))here in my textarea text new line is \n ..and Environment.NewLine is actually \r\n. so it is not replacing with a break satement.What should i use instead of Environment.NewLine. i can just hardcode \n to replace with . If i dnt want to do that way is there any environment variable i can use for.

Comment: It seems that this question is quite different from the original question. Since it has nothing to do with SQL Server actually saving the data I would suggest that you retitle this question or delete it and open a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  style="white-space: pre-line" will give an impression of new line.